# Proper contents of first three lines of xml doc using xsl stylesheet

Tags: c#, html, css, xml, xslt

I inherited a report generator that creates an xml file and formats it using xsl/css. I'm not very familiar with web page creation. The .html file is created by this line of code:

```
xslt.Transform(XmlReader.Create(xmlStream), writer);
```

and is displayed in a .NET 4.5.2 System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser object. The report looks fine. Also renders nicely in IE 11, and not as well in Firefox (some background colors missing).

More importantly, though, a user is reporting problems converting the .html into .pdf using Adobe Acrobat (some images are sized incorrectly) so I'm investigating the quality of the .html formatting. I opened the .xml file created by the report generator in Visual Studio 2013 and it flagged the first 2 lines with problems:

```
<?xml:stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mydir\report.xsl" ?>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

The first line is flagged with error: "Invalid characters in processing instruction target"
The second line is flagged with error: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document with no white space characters allowed to appear before it."

How would I structure those lines to make Visual Studio happy (without degrading the end result, of course).

In case it is useful, here is the first line of report.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
```

Visual Studio seems happy with that file.

Thank you.

Comment: Incidentally, the 'Invalid characters' was almost certainly referring to the \ in the href attribute- as seen from Martin's answer, that should be a `/`.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Thanks for pointing that out. I hadn't noticed that difference in Martin's answer and actually Visual Studio didn't point it out either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML declaration needs to come first and the processing instruction should be `xml-stylesheet`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mydir/report.xsl" ?>
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Comment: Yes, errors are gone now. Thanks! While trying to figure out how to emit them in that order, I ended up with a .xml file that didn't have the stylesheet line in it at all, but the resulting .html still renders perfectly. What is the purpose of that line?

Comment: If you load an XML document having `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mydir/report.xsl" ?>` directly into a browser the browser, as long as it supports XSLT, will apply the stylesheet `mydir/report.xsl` to render the transformation result. If you do the transformation in your .NET code and only want to load the HTML document created into the browser then the XML document does not need the `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Thanks for quick responses today.